# Проблема в написании функцию map, которая будет принимать в качестве аргумента массив arr и функцию

Tags: javascript

ЗдравствуйтеСтоит следующая задача

1. Написать функцию map, которая будет принимать в качестве  аргумента массив arr и функцию, которая в свою очередь будет осуществлять преобразование каждого элемента массива в вид.   `"<li class="list-group-item">Tom</li>"`.   2. Вывести элементы трансформированного массива в ul с id="list". Вывод должен осуществляться в отсортированном по алфавиту виде

Что я предпринял:

```
<div class="container">
      <h1>List of my friends</h1>

      <ul id="list" class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Example</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

//JS

function createList() {
  let list = document.createElement("ul");
  let listItem;
  let currentLetter = '';

  for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
      let item = arr[i];
      let firstLetter = item.charAt(0);

      if (currentLetter != firstLetter) {
          currentLetter = firstLetter;
      }

      listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.innerHTML = item;

      list.appendChild(listItem);
  }

  return list;
}

document.body.appendChild(createList());
```

Вывод имен в браузере осуществляется в отсортированном порядке. Сколько не лазил по МДН и не читал про преобразование массивов, смекалки и знаний не хватило. Прошу, подскажите ресурс с подходящей информацией или возможный алгоритм, как выполнить все условия задачи. Спасибо и с уважением

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки, есть встроенная функция [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
function map(arr, fn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = fn(arr[i], i, arr);
    // Вызывает полученную функцию fn,
    // заменяет элемент массива на результат её вызова (то, что вернет return)
    // * Три аргумента переданы по традиции. Здесь нужен только 1-й
  }
}

let arr = ["Tom", "John", "Pumba", "Anna"];

map(arr, function(name) {
  // name == arr[i]
  return '<li class="list-group-item">' + name + '</li>';
});

let list = document.querySelector("#list");

list.innerHTML = arr.sort((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : 1).join("");
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

У массивов также есть свой метод [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), но он создает и возвращает новый массив, не меняя значения исходного массива.

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался ! )

Comment: Да, такого поведения от map никак не ожидаешь :) Будет сюрприз кому-то!